# Elasticsearch Kibana Graph plugin authentication

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, graph, kibana

Hi I just installed graph plugin to my elasticsearch and kibana servers, but when I make a request in graph is asking for some authentication credentials, but I don't have it.

Any idea where I can configure this?

BTW: I dont have shield installed.
Regards,

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU8bM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I found that is a bug in graph, the error is for the license but graph ask for authentication.

So installing a trial license solve the problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Kibana does not have security authentication.In Kibana configuration, you have authentication fields, to connect to elasticsearch, depending on how you have configured it.So, if you're prompted for credentials, it is from Elasticsearch, or in your Apache/Nginx/whatever configuration if you have. Kibana configuration file is in /opt/kibana/config folder if you have installed it with package; with custom installation, quite same tree, find "config" folder.In this file, check first how Kibana connects to elasticsearch, and comment those fields if you want.